# ROS Answers SE migration: Rosdep Error

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a newbie to Linux and ROS.

Have successfully installed Ubuntu and (I believe) ROS and am in the process of installing various stacks.

One stack is the iheart-robotics rovio driver.

I've attempted to follow the directions to the point I am supposed to issue "rosdep install rovio" from within the installation directory.

It spins for a few seconds and reports an error.  The sequence is:

```
mike@mike-EP45C-UD3R:~/mikeros/iheart-ros-pkg$ dir
ihr_demos  ihr_tools  README  rovio
mike@mike-EP45C-UD3R:~/mikeros/iheart-ros-pkg$ cd rovio
mike@mike-EP45C-UD3R:~/mikeros/iheart-ros-pkg/rovio$ rosdep install rovio
executing this script:
 set -o errexit
#No Packages to install
mike@mike-EP45C-UD3R:~/mikeros/iheart-ros-pkg/rovio$
```

I presume this is an error.  Or does this indicate that the dependencies have previously been resolved?

Many thanks...

-Mike

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9113/rosdep-error/) by [mbahr](https://answers.ros.org/users/106/mbahr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2011-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That means everything is already installed.

Those messages are confusing. I opened `rosdep` enhancement ticket #3346 to make the output clearer.

http://https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3346

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This does mean that all dependencies required were already detected on the system.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1